# Getting the user to enter a file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

" Your assignment is to prompt the user to enter the filename with the path on disk.  If the file does not exist in the specified location, your program should exit with a suitable error message" 
Hi everyone, so this is where I'm having an issue, I was able to get the user to enter a file name like this..

```
1.         cout<< "enter the data file name you wish to open";
2.         cin >>file;
3.         indata.open(file.c_str());
4.         outdata.open(file.c_str());
```

The second part of the question is if the file does not exist, the program should make an error, how would I go about doing so, say my file name is txt.source, but the user enters lil.pol how do I make it say there is an error, or other words how do I make the file name desired the only one the computer will accept?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is try to open the file and if it fails to open issue a message through `std::cerr` like this:

```
std::ifstream indata(file.c_str());

if(!indata) // failed to open
{
    std::cerr << "Error: could not open file: " << file << std::endl;
    return 1; // error code
}

// use indata here (its open)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

reading/writing data:

```
void createfile()
{
    ofstream file_handle("test.txt");
    if (!file_handle)
        return;

    //add record:
    file_handle << "firstname1" << endl;
    file_handle << "lastname1" << endl;
    file_handle << "college1" << endl;
    file_handle << "1001" << endl;

    //add another record:
    file_handle << "firstname2" << endl;
    file_handle << "lastname2" << endl;
    file_handle << "college2" << endl;
    file_handle << "1002" << endl;

    //remember each record is 4 lines, each field is single line
    //this is the file format
}

int main()
{
    createfile();

    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "file not found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ofstream fout("out.txt");//note, it's a different name than input file
    if (!fout)
    {
        cout << "cannot create new file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    char buffer[1000];

    while (fin)
    {
        cout << "attempting to read record:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            fin.getline(buffer, 1000, '\n');
            if (!fin) break;

            cout << buffer << endl;//write to screen
            fout << buffer << endl;//write to file

            if (i == 3)
            {
                //buffer is expected to be a number!
                int number = atoi(buffer);
                //multiply by random number 2, just testing
                cout << number * 2 << endl; 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just make a loop and ask for new entry if the file name is wrong.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream indata;
    string fname;
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "enter fname, zero to exit\n";
        cin >> fname;
        if (fname == "0")
            return 0;
        indata.open(fname);
        if (indata)
            break;//file is valid and has been opened now
        cout << "file not found, try again\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So that's really helpful but how does it know what the correct file name is, so because file is a string I could enter different names and it will accept all of them. I want the file name to be something specific

Comment: This is a very simple task. Galik's answer does exactly what the assignment asks for. If file name is wrong then file is not on the computer, open operation fails. There is nothing else to it. I put a more fancy version which asks for re-entry if there was a mistake the first time, don't worry about that for now. Next step is to create a file for `outdata`. This time it doesn't matter if the file is not on the computer, the program will create the file and it's ready for writing. Just make sure you enter a different file name for `outdata`.

Comment: So I guess whats confusing me is that I have a list of data, names colleges  and a number that I'm trying to have output when the file is opened and I don't understand how to get them to output. Also when i have indata.open(file) the open is red and won't work

Comment: That's a different question. I made an edit to make a basic example. If that answers your question please mark this as answered. For a new question you can start a new question, more people will see it. Also this topic is on-hold, other people cannot answer.